# Ruby on Rails - Breaking down a hash of hashes to include caching of queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, hash

I have a hash of hashes that I use to create a stacked column chart. Along the x axis, I have the days of the week and the y axis is the total points for the day for each goal, stacked to the total points for the day overall.

Here is the method in my controller:

```
def goal_xp_by_day

  # Create an array of goals to iterate through only if they have activities
  # recorded in the last 7 days.
  days_goals = current_user.goals.select { |g| g.empty_days}

  # Iterate through goals and for each goal, create a hash of days and points
  goals = days_goals.map do |goal|
    days = {}
    (Date.today-6..Date.today).each do |day|

      # Pass the day to a method which uses the paramater 
      # to calculate the points for that period
      days[day.strftime("%a")] = goal.daily_goal_xp(day)
    end
    {
      name: goal.name,
      data: days
    }
  end
  render json: goals
end
```

As the days pass, I know the results for each day (excluding the current) will not change but the current day's result could change at any time so caching the entire chart makes no sense. I'd like to find a away to cache the data for the previous 6 days to prevent excessive querying but I'm not sure how to go about breaking up this method to query the last 6 days, cache it and the run the queries to calculate the results for today then finally merge it all together to create the updated graph.

I was thinking of passing a parameter like the date of the day into the cache_key and possibly using some form of Russian doll caching for each hash. Is this something that can be done in the controller? I know usually they're used in the view files but in this case, the results are returned in the controller.

If there's a way to improve the efficiency of these queries, I would really appreciate some advice/pointers, even if caching isn't an option.

Comment: one easy way would be for example to first implement a model function `goal_xp_by_day(_selected_goals)` which calculates the json results for the previuos days. The controller then just calls the model function with the params. Then cache the results in a file and check the file age at every call of the function. If file age older than x days/hours create a new file. As you need the results in json, it makes sense to save them to a temp .json file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, something like this could be done at the controller level. You could wrap the entire method contents with a general cache call and then wrap each infrequently changing section of the code with another key.

Something like this might get you pointed down the right road:

```
(Date.today-6..Date.today).each do |day|
  days[day.strftime("%a")] = Rails.cache.fetch("day-goal", day) do 
    goal.daily_goal_xp(day)
  end
end
```

This will result in a cache key for a given day which won't change. Don't forget to update your cache keys with any model instances which might cause the cache to expire.